# Get heroku database address and credentials instead of DATABASE_URL

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm deploying an app that requires the DB info to be passed as separate args, e.g.

```
$ someapp --db-host=example.com --db-port=5433 --db-name=mydb --db-user=me --db-password=mypass
```

When looking at what `heroku` offers, it looks like the only thing available is the `DATABASE_URL`. I can of course parse its value in `Procfile` and extract all the necessary stuff, currently I'm thinking of something like a small helper script, e.g. `parse_db_url.py`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import make_url


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = make_url(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
    env = f'''PG_USER={url.username}
PG_PASSWORD={url.password}
PG_HOST={url.host}
PG_PORT={url.port}
PG_DBNAME={url.database}'''
    print(env)
```

and `eval`ing it in the `Procfile`:

```
web: eval $(python parse_db_url.py) && someapp --db-host=$PG_HOST ...
```

etc, but is it the right way of doing that or am I simply overlooking something? If this is of relevance, I'm testing on the free plan atm, but moving to a hobby plan when happy with the deployment.

Comment: You can add your own environment variables to hold the configuration (under Settings -> Config vars). Just add them and set your Procfile to `web: someapp --db-host=$PG_HOST ...`

Comment: @yonili if I'm reading the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres) correctly, I can't persist the db connection in `.env` because: _The value of your app’s `DATABASE_URL` config var might change at any time. You should not rely on this value either inside or outside your Heroku app._

Comment: Yes - looks like you right. Than I assume if you can't change the app itself you should go with something like you did.

Comment: There's nothing that can be set as a config variable that will deconstruct the connection string into the relevant parts. A quick google seems to indicate that slqalchemy supports connecting directly to `DATABASE_URL`. Why are you trying to parse it manually?

Comment: @RangerRanger Again, I'm trying to parse it manually because the app I need to deploy does not accept database urls, requiring separate db connection args instead. For that, I use `sqlalchemy` because I don't want to write the parsing myself.